# How long did Adi Shankaracharya live?

Tags: shiva, worship, adi-shankaracharya, life-span

I have read that Adi Shankaracharya's parents were childless for many years and they worshipped Lord Shiva, so that they will be blessed with a son. Then the Lord appeared in their dream and asked them "**You can choose to have either one extraordinary son with a short life or many ordinary sons**".

They chose the extraordinary son.

It is said that Adi Shankaracharya left his house at the age of 12 and became a sanyasi. I want to know after that how long he lived.

Comment: He left the house at 7-8 yrs of age and became a guruji at age 12. His god-given life span was 8 years (some say 16) and the gurus and sages, pleased with his scholastic and vedantic achievement and potential, granted him 8 more years(some do not ACK this part and believe the original god-granted lifespan is 16 yrs .  Sage Vysasa granted him another 16 years and ordered him to continue his life's work. He left the mortal coil at the age of 32.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting from [here](http://www.astrojyoti.com/adishankaracharya.htm) ,

> **Shankara’s dates**
>
> Modern scholarship is agreed on dates in the 8th century C.E., though
>   it has proved impossible to reach agreement on Shankara’s precise
>   dates of birth or death. Some religious groups, however, ascribe
>   B.C.E. dates to him. If these dates were true, then much of what is
>   claimed about his activities, especially his debates with Buddhists
>   and Jains, is thrown into doubt.
>
> Of the major Shankara Mathams active today, the Kanchi, Dwaraka, and
>   Puri ascribe the dates 509–477 B.C.E. to Shankara. The Sringeri
>   Peetham, on the other hand, accepts the 788–820 C.E. dates.
>
> .....**Even though he lived for only thirty-two years,** his impact on India
>   and on Hinduism cannot be stressed enough, as he countered the
>   increasing sacerdotalism (the belief that priests can mediate between
>   humans and god) of the masses, and reintroduced a purer form of Vedic
>   thought.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara) too he died at the age of 32.

So,20 years more will be the answer to your question.

Comment: Could be either, he came after Buddha who is said to have come in 4th century BCE